# Быть или не быть async/await

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, task

В коде

```
async Task<Result> Work()
{
   var data = await GetData();
   //do something
}
```

Есть два варианта написания GetData

```
async Task<object> GetData()
{
  await Service.GetDataAsync();
}
```

или

```
Task<object> GetData()
{
  return Service.GetDataAsync();
}
```

Значительна ли разница между методами?

Что лучше по производительности?

Что происходит под "капотом" в данном случае с async/await в двух словах?

Comment: @aepot Да, разобрался, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тема много где описана.

Кратко: по ключевому слову `async` компилятор генерит асинхронную машину состояний из метода. Это достаточно сложная система, чтобы `await` смог в ней работать правильно.

Во втором случае вы выполнили оптимизацию, то есть убрали машину состояний, потому что если бы даже она была, у нее было бы всего одно значимое состояние (всего два).

Поэтому второй метод быстрее. Но эта оптимизация далеко не всегда доступна.

Например эта конструкция не будет работать.

```cs
// не сработает
Task<object> GetData()
{
    try
    {
        return Service.GetDataAsync();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Потому что возврат `Task` из метода произойдет раньше, чем сам метод отработает, логично же? Поэтому перехват исключения здесь возможен только из стартовой синхронной части вызываемого метода.

И эта тоже не будет работать.

```cs
// не сработает
Task<object> GetData()
{
    using var obj = new MyDispoasbleObject();
    return Service.GetDataAsync(obj);
}
```

Потому что объект `obj` будет уничтожен раньше, чем метод `GetDataAsync` завершится.

Ну и если в асинхронном методе более одного `await`, либо имеющийся один `await` не в конце метода - такая оптимизация в принципе не доступна.