# Как сделать асинхронный метод из синхронного?

Tags: c#, async-await, асинхронность

У меня есть условный синхронный метод (далее "GenString"). Я решил сделать его асинхронным. У меня получилось 2 варианта. Но я хотел бы знать, как это сделать правильно? Буду благодарен за примеры.
Первый пример тут я обернул синхронный метод в в Task.Run и вывожу его с помощью await

```
async Task<string> GenStringAsynV2(long arrayLength)
{
    return await Task.Run(() => GenString(arrayLength));
}
```

Это первый вариан этого метода сдеся я просто запускаю задачу и возращаю ее

```
Task<string> GenStringAsynV1(long arrayLength)
{
    return Task.Run(() => GenString(arrayLength));
}
```

Это же условный метод который я хотел бы сделать асинхронным не меня его. Он небыл создан для каких то целей, просто задача которую я придумал на коленке

```
string GenString(long arrayLength)
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    StringBuilder result = new();
    for (long i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
    {
        result.Append(i).Append(" + ");
    }

    sw.Stop();
    StringBuilder timeWork = new StringBuilder("GenString: ")
        .Append(sw.Elapsed)
        .Append("; String Length: ")
        .Append(result.Length);
    Debug.WriteLine("End");
    return timeWork.ToString();
}
```

Comment: [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) [Don't Use Task.Run in the Implementation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html)

Comment: Дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1350412/373567? у вас обычная CPU-bound операция. Код выглядит правильно в обоих случаях, во втором он просто слегка оптимизирован.